# Parse gradient string into colors

Tags: javascript, regex, string, gradient

I have these strings

```
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(196,97,97,1), #222222)
linear-gradient(90deg, #222222, #222222)
linear-gradient(90deg, #222, #22222280)
linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(196,97,97,1), rgba(196,97,97,1))
```

Instead 90deg, there can also be radial, but my question is how can I get only colors from these string so the output would be

```
[rgba(196,97,97,1), #222222]
[#222222, #222222]
[#222, #22222280]
[rgba(196,97,97,1), rgba(196,97,97,1)]
```

When the are no hex and 2x rgba I managed to do it with `.match(/rgba\(.*?\)/g)` but how do I do it, where there are hex and rgba, hex and hex with opacity etc?

Comment: Did you try `.match(/rgba\(.*?\)|#\w+/g)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
.match(/rgba\([^()]*\)|#\w+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ngSwj/1/). *Details*:

- `rgba\([^()]*\)` - `rgba(` substring, then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char
- `|` - or
- `#\w+` - a `#` char and then one or more letters, digits or `_`. You may also use the "hex" chars pattern here, `#[a-fA-F0-9]+`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(196,97,97,1), #222222)',
'linear-gradient(90deg, #222222, #222222)',
'linear-gradient(90deg, #222, #22222280)',
'linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(196,97,97,1), rgba(196,97,97,1))'];
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '->', text.match(/rgba\([^()]*\)|#\w+/g))
}
```